# Как создать базу данных на чистом C#?

Tags: c#, база-данных, xml, dataset

Вопрос такой: нужно создать базу данных, не используя SQL и дополнительных средств работы с БД, как MongoDB, RavenDB и т.д.

Материалы в сети имеются, но старые, поэтому хотелось бы уточнить здесь. Если я правильно понимаю, можно сделать это через DataSet, с использованием XML. Есть ли еще какие-то методы?
Возможно, Вы знаете какие-то источники, в которых хорошо об этом написано?

Большое спасибо.

Comment: `File.WriteAllText()` - чем вам не создание базы данных? Ну или придумайте вовсе свой формат, свой способ хранения и используйте, раз не хотите готовое...

Comment: Очень многое зависит от того, что вкладывается в понятие "база данных". Для кого то и csv-файл с возможностью поиска по нему - база, а кому то подавай раширяемые по запросу таблицы с праймари и секондари ключами